# Preloads's Adaptive readahead daemon won't run on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, services, preload

thank you in advance.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and for somereason i can't get Adaptive readahead daemon to run, when i try to run it from terminal i encounter:

```
** (process:7371): ERROR **: cannot open /var/log/preload.log: Permission denied
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

EDIT :

In the app description in the Ubuntu Software Center in says : " this program is run from a terminal : preload "

so that's exactly whats i did, and got this message.

I could really use this application.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Please expand your Question: What is your input in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

how are you running it ?

should run as service ,

```
sudo service preload restart
```

or you can try ($USER can be replaced if you want to run with some other user )

```
sudo chown -R $USER /var/log/preload.log
```

Comment: I've edited the question , i run it from terminal as it says in the program's description .

Comment: To be specific after i run it , it doesn't appear in the service --status-all command

Comment: did you run is `sudo service preload restart` ?


if you want to run it from console , as a command , try giving destinations where you have write permissions 
like below 
`preload -l /tmp/some.log -f -d -s /tmp/some.state`